# sed variable with $ sign

Tags: sed

I'm sure this has been asked before and I'm sorry if it has but I can't find it.

I'm trying to replace 'mypassword' in the following with a dovecot SHA512-CRYPT password but the dollar sign is screwing things up and I can't figure out how to escape it.

The password generated from `doveadm pw -s SHA512-CRYPT -p ${rootemailpw}` looks something like the following which you can see has a few dollar signs in it:

```
{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$sujue1sr0abLZisA$Dq1qtz422woyR/A4wDaJ9JYByKHis27FO.mO5EfUCDuI/PRSawxgCRGA3Oq/LE4Nbr32nCr4731BCPIotmRNR0
```

Here is the script I'm using:

```
rootemailpw=$(</dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c12)
rootpw=$(doveadm pw -s SHA512-CRYPT -p ${rootemailpw})

cat <<'EOF' > tmp
USE `postfix`;
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`,`password`) VALUES ('root@localhost','mypassword');
EOF

sed -i "s/mypassword/${rootpw}/" tmp
```

So how to escape the $ signs properly in `s/mypassword/${rootpw}/`

Comment: Does the `rootpw` variable contain a newline?

Comment: no. if you have dovecot installed, run `doveadm pw -s SHA512-CRYPT -p somepassword` to see the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SHA hashes may contain slash characters (`/`), which is the usual sed delimiter. `sed` supports most delimiters so one way around it is to use a different one, e.g. a pipe character (`|`):

```
pw=$(doveadm pw -s SHA512-CRYPT -p somepassword)
echo password | sed "s|password|$pw|"
```

Output:

```
{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$qtXJPWaMbX3l8zMW$mXWuax8NG9Wa1AkFdcClA5vw2T3407uBdImKNNbcBd/CUkS5NafjZnQ5ow.IubyLujU5ohS8PWogdNoPiF4d//
```

Comment: that works if you surround pw with single quotes but not if you generate the pw from `rootpw=$(doveadm pw -s SHA512-CRYPT -p ${rootemailpw})`

Comment: @Christian: The SHA hashes contain slashes which trips sed up, see update.

Comment: OF COURSE!! It wasnt the dollar signs, it was the forward slashes haha! Excellent. Thank you Thor!

Answer (score 0):

With the following in ./tmp:

```
USE `postfix`;
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`,`password`) VALUES ('root@localhost','mypassword');
```

Executing `rootpw='1234$asdf' ; cat tmp | sed "s/mypassword/${rootpw}/"` will replace *mypassword* with the contents of *${rootpw}* like so:

```
USE `postfix`;
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`,`password`) VALUES ('root@localhost','1234$asdf');
```

for:

1. `rootpw='1234$asdf'` sets the environment variable
2. `cat tmp | sed "s/mypassword/${rootpw}/"` replaces *mypassword* with "1234$asdf"

Use single quotes on the variable.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: you also dont need to use export. Also `sed -i` is inline edit, so you dont need to `cat tmp |` either. and this `"s/mypassword/\$\{rootpw\}/"` is crazy, why dont you just do `'s/mypassword/${rootpw}/'`.. anyway, that is not the answer but thank you.

Comment: your double quotes are problematic when setting *$* in the variable